# Uikit Progress bar on Uikit Table

Tags: html, getuikit

I have problem putting a `uikit progress bar` inside a `uikit table cell`, i have searched for `getuikit` for [`progress bar`](http://getuikit.com/docs/progress.html) and [`table`](http://getuikit.com/docs/table.html) documentation I googled everything but found no any good community or resources out there.

**Here is my simplified html file for table:**

```
<table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-overflow-container">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Employee
            </th>
            <th>
                <label class="uk-form-label" for="name" style="font-weight: lighter;">
                    Contact
                </label>
            </th>
            <th>
                Workplace/Position
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Work Completed (%)
            </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Luigi Lascuña</td>
            <td>Igi@skyes8.com</td>
            <td>Main Office/General Manager</td>
            <td>Regular</td>
            <td class="uk-progress">
                <div class="uk-progress-bar" style="width: 40%;">40%</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here is my output:**

[image: employee table]

> There result will only display the `40%` text inside a table cell but
>   not just like in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just include the `components/progress.css` to my styles block in the head of the main html file. This solved my problem!

[image: employee list]